# Can a Catholic visiting Protestant Parents attend the Parents Church?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, ecclesiology

Once I am in college and fully convert to Catholicism, would it be considered wrong (in terms of violating Catholic teaching) to attend my Parents Protestant Church? Note that I would probably be attending Mass later in the day, so this isn’t a question about “replacing” the mass with a Protestant service.

Comment: Gal. 5:1-6  There is simplicity in Christ, not an overabundance of laws.  Will you refrain from honoring your parents because it is "corban"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is forbidden for Catholics to engage in *communicatio in sacris*—joining non-Catholics in their worship services:

> [1917 Canon 1258](https://books.google.com/books?id=2XbtF6Y21LUC&pg=PA426) §1 It is not licit for the faithful by any manner to assist actively or to have a part in the sacred [rites] of non-Catholics.

<sup>cf. Dom Augustine's [*A Commentary on the New Code of Canon Law* on '17 Can. 1258](https://archive.org/stream/1917CodeOfCanonLawCommentary#page/n2581/mode/2up)</sup>

This law is expressed in the 1983 code, in the section "Delicts against religion and the unity of the Church," as:

> [1983 Can. 1365](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P52.HTM) A person guilty of prohibited participation in sacred rites (*communicatio in sacris*) is to be punished with a just penalty.

<sup>cf. [this commentary on '83 Can. 1365](https://books.google.com/books?id=JKgZEjvB5cEC&pg=PA1577)</sup>

Comment: So the answer is no… hmmm. This is difficult. What if I did not participate in communion?

Comment: Given how widely this is not followed, I'm wondering if "assist actively or have a part in" means "assist in the carrying out of" rather than just attending?

Comment: The commentary also says: "A  passive  or  merely  material  presence  may be  tolerated,  for  reasons  of  civil  duty  or  honor,  at  funerals, weddings,  and  similar  celebrations,  provided  no danger  of  perversion  or  scandal  arises  from  this  assistance".

Comment: @DJClayworth That's actually the second part of the [1917 Code](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7786) canon 1258 §2 (not the commentary).